# Make a "git commit" on condition on the Jenkins server

Tags: git, jenkins

We have a jenkins server that builds our .Net code. We have severals parameters for this job.

This job already update the AssemblyVersion to the one used in the build.
We would like to have the possibility to commit those AssemblyVersion back to git.

Most of the time we won't do it, but every minor version we would like to be able to "commit" the changes made by the job.

I've added a Boolean parameter, but currently I can't see how I can put a condition for the build.

I've seen this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin but it doesn't have a git commit as action.

Note: Inside jenkins, we are using jgit

How can I achieve this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "Windows batch command script"-step in which you perform the git tasks you need to do. From a windows batch script command you can access your boolean parameter as follows: `$MyBooleanParameter`

So for example (not tested and i'm not a batch guru):

```
if $MyBooleanParameter equ true (
    git add Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
    git commit -m "Updated assembly version"
    git push
)
```

Comment: any idea how to use JGIT instead of GIT?

Comment: no sorry, but why not install GIT on your build server and use that instead?

Comment: We were having issue of environnement with GIT(since jenkins is running inside a JVM and stuff), and it was recommended to me by stackoverflow people to use JGIT.